# Can GitHub Action commit an artifact to a branch?

Tags: git, github-actions

**TL;DR**

Is it possible for GitHub Action to commit the built artifact to a special branch (e.g. branch `prod`)?

**Background / Why I ask**

I am currently building my first deployment pipeline. I have already tried two strategies and am not really satisfied with any of them. What I have already tried:

1. Strategy: build the laravel and vue app; packed the bundle and pushed it to the server via scp; unpacked it there.
2. Strategy: GitHub action logs onto my server via ssh and does a git pull from the master.

With the first solution, I don't like the future update capability. Also if I use the storage app folder for uploads within the app they don't stay persistent.

With the second solution I like the way to get the status via git pull but I see problems with building the application on the server. Because via `git pull` I don't load the dependencies like `node_modules` folder. I would always have to build the app on the server and delete the `node_modules` and `dev-dependencies` in the deployment process.

Comment: A github action can run arbitrary commands. It can do whatever you want, given appropriate credentials.

Comment: @larsks Thank you! Is there already a GitHub action package to create a branch in my repository? What do you mean by: "given appropriate credentials."

Comment: You need to set the  `permissions: contents: write` element to your workflow to be able to push back to GitHub.

Answer (score 3):

I use the following scriptlet to commit things:

```
    # add fetch-depth:0 to ensure the whole repo is pulled down
    - uses: actions/checkout@b4ffde65f46336ab88eb53be808477a3936bae11 # v4
      with:
        fetch-depth: 0
    
    - name: Switch to the other branch
      run: |
         & git switch other-branch
      shell: pwsh 

    # Do your thing
    # ...
 
    - name: Commit data
      shell: pwsh 
      run: |
          & git config --local user.email "41898282+github-actions[bot]@users.noreply.github.com"
          & git config --local user.name "github-actions[bot]"
          & git add .
          & git diff HEAD --exit-code | Out-Null
          if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0)
          {
              & git commit -m "Adding new seat assignment data"
              & git push origin other-branch
          }
```

Be sure to add the additional permissions to the top of the workflow file:

```
permissions: 
  contents: write
```

Comment: Thank your for your answer. But i have some questions: 
1. What means the hash after the @: `actions/checkout@b4ffde65f46336ab88eb53be808477a3936bae11`
2. what means `fetch-depth: 0`?
3. What mean `shell: pwsh`? -> maybe Powershell?
4. Where comes the var `$LASTEXITCODE`? 
5. `permissions: 
  contents: write` i have to add to the yml file, right?

Comment: 1. It's the Sha of the latest version. You can also use `@v4`. 2. Fetch depth is how much history to grab. Depth 1 will only get the latest commit. Depth 5 the last 5, 0 gets the full history. You'll need that to be able to commit back. 4. Calling an external binary will set the magic LASTEXITCODE variable. 5. Yes, add that to the top, stage or job level if your workflow file.

Comment: Thanks to you! I can already do something with that. Even if I think it will still be a long way to the finished CD. But it's also my first pipe. Cheers and have a nice night!

Comment: So I assume that you had a similar thought about the workflow? Because I didn't know if my question sounded completely absurd with how I would like my workflow to be.

Comment: I have a few workflows that commit code back in. You could also consider creating a release using `gh release create`